# Method calls inside LINQ select (efficiency)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, foreach, performance

I have an efficiency-based question regarding LINQ vs a standard foreach loop.

I have a method, which does approximately the following

```
var foos = users.Select(this.GenerateNullableFoo).Where(foo => foo != null);
```

This turned out, for some reason, to be horrendously slow.  Using timestamps I was able to determine that the point of slowness was exactly at the iteration of the select (time from final return statement to beginning of next method call) was vastly slower (13 seconds) than anything else (total time <= 14 seconds).

When replaced with the following, the entire process time was reduced to under 1 second per iteration.

New code:

```
var foos= new List<Foo>();

foreach (var user in users)
{
    var foo = GenerateNullableFoo(user);

        foo.IfNotNull(f => foos.Add(foo));
}
```

As far as I'm aware, my code works and there is nothing wrong with the new code, however, I am completely baffled as to why using the Select above was more than 10 times slower than a foreach doing seemingly the same process.  Is there any insight as to what differences might account for this?

Also, the entire List is not saved until *after* said select/foreach at which time a batch call is made to the db.

EDIT: The entire code block from the point of origin to finish (and termination) is as follows:

```
//Code snippet pictured above
_repo.SaveFoo(Foos);
//at this point, the code terminates and is finished
```

Comment: How are you using the query you have?  If you're, for example, iterating the results several times that would easily explain the behavior.

Comment: Have you tried `var foos = users.Select(this.GenerateNullableFoo).Where(foo => foo != null)` *.ToList()* `;`? That would create code that is more similar to the `foreach`.

Comment: Why do you have `foo != null` in the top one and `foo.IfNotNull(..)` in the bottom?

Comment: Those two are not equivalent. The second builds a list, where as the first one creates an IEnumerable. As the other comments point out, using the result of the first one many times will result in many executions. The list will simply iterate over a collection on subsequent uses

Comment: I'm not sure how my code would be using the results of the select multiple times.  The only code after these snippets is a bulk save
_repo.SaveAll(Foos);

the code then finishes and terminates the process completely.

@TimS. The where clause works on the generated foo to make sure it isn't null, which is the same as what is being done in the bottom IfNotNull clause.  Both items are just checking "if the foo isn't null, keep it in the list/add it to the list"

Comment: @Arumat How does `SaveFoo` looks like?

Comment: The difference in speed does not depend on save being called and so I will refrain from delving into it (speed did not change even if I completely removed the save block, which was done for isolation testing).  It is a simple database save using NHibernate.

Comment: Well, it _does_ make a difference the way we can see your code. Without the save block there is no iteration at all because the LINQ query is not executed. _With_ the code block it is (apparently) and it looks like a database action is executed for each iteration. But we would need to see `SaveFoo` to see if that's right. Anyway, the point is that in your current (possibly contrived) code, execution of the LINQ query happens in SaveFoo.

Comment: Often you need to be careful with Linq because you may execute stuff too many times

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, a LINQ expression is not projected to a result set until it is iterated on by code which means all you have done is declare the logic.

The code you have **not** posted is then causing the LINQ expression to be projected, and most likely many times.

The shortest way to solve this is simply add **.ToList()** to your expression, this will project the expression immediately meaning other code can use the in-memory and already projected list without causing additional projections/calculations/etc etc..

Cheers, Aaron